# Using CursorLoaders in a Searchable Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to create a Searchable Activity to be used with the Action Bar.
I have a CursorAdapter supplying the data from a ContentProvider.

What I have trouble understanding is why does the API examples, ie, searchableDictonary, performs a managedQuery instead of doing something async with the CursorLoaders.

Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this example is fairly old and `CursorLoaders` didn't exist at the time. If loaders work for you, do use them. Are you having any specific problem?

Comment: Nope. Just wondering about design pattern. I guess I'll like to see if anyone know of any good examples. But I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: The compatibility library has some examples. For real-life usage, get ASOP code and grep for 'CursorLoader'. Github might be a good source as well.